# Does Telegram have a way to show carousels with Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram

I'm developing a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework, on Facebook Messenger the carousel shows as it should, but in Telegram it shows as 2 different cards on two different messages.

Doesn't Telegram support carousels or is it my fault?

Code:

```
    public async Task Carousel(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {
        var act = await activity;
        //carousel
        var replyToConversation = context.MakeMessage();
        replyToConversation.Text = "2+ Cards are a Carousel";
        replyToConversation.Recipient = message.From;
        replyToConversation.Type = "message";
        replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        //1
        List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
        cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Asimo_look_new_design.jpg/330px-Asimo_look_new_design.jpg"));
        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot",
            Type = "openUrl",
            Title = "WikiPedia Page"
        };
        cardButtons.Add(plButton);
        HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "I'm a hero card",
            Subtitle = "Robot Wikipedia Page",
            Images = cardImages,
            Buttons = cardButtons
        };
        Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
        //2
        List<CardImage> cardImages2 = new List<CardImage>();
        cardImages2.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9b/FANUC_6-axis_welding_robots.jpg/330px-FANUC_6-axis_welding_robots.jpg"));
        List<CardAction> cardButtons2 = new List<CardAction>();
        CardAction plButton2 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot",
            Type = "openUrl",
            Title = "WikiPedia Page"
        };
        cardButtons2.Add(plButton);
        HeroCard plCard2 = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "I'm a hero card",
            Subtitle = "Robot Wikipedia Page",
            Images = cardImages2,
            Buttons = cardButtons2
        };
        Attachment plAttachment2 = plCard2.ToAttachment();
        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment2);
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not your fault. Per the [Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Telegram?f=Carousel&e=example1), the carousel in Telegram has a down-rendered appearance.